# "edit_published_posts" and "edit_other_post" issue

Tags: posts, user-roles, capabilities

I need to modify a roles capabilities for post editing:

- User can modify his own post (publish status doesn't matter)
- User can modify others posts (only as long as they are not published)

I played around with `edit_posts` + `edit_other_posts` + `edit_published_posts` but that not work as I expected.

Here a schema of what I try to do:

```
  Modify =>   |own post | other user post
not published |    √    |        √
published     |    √    |        X
```

Comment: Would you mind showing us (in code in an [edit]) how you tried to alter the roles?

Comment: I think altering generic roles capabilities is not the right directions here, because capabilitites should change based on post status. Try to play with meta capabilitities [a starting point](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types)